# Add style to an existing EventListener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I made this eventlistener function in JS:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
   
  if (event.code == "KeyA") {
    let audioA = new Audio("https://docs.google.com/...");
    audioA.currentTime = 0;
    audioA.play();
  }
```

Now I wanted to add changes in style too, but I have no idea how to add these changes, nothing seems to work. I tried `*classname*.style.backgroundColor = "red";` after the "audioA.play()", but nothing changed. I also tried to keep the class "playing" (which should be the result of pressing the button) visible and make in invisible in JS BEFORE pressing the button, but this was also not working, the style was still "playing". How can I add the "playing" changes to my existing code? The sound's working perfectly.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sounds like what you need dis `document.querySelector(*className*).style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: Are you trying to set the background of the play button in red ?

Comment: Create a CSS class and then add it to an ID on the page.

Comment: Thx Sphinx for your respond, unfortunately, it didn't work either. Do I set it after the "audioA.paly();?

Comment: For clarification, when someones presses the key A on the keyboard, Sound is to hear. I also want to do a visible change. I saw a JS tutorial by Wes Bos javascript30 Drum Kit, but he is doing it totally different from the beginning. I wanted to know if it is possible to add the visible change to my code I already wrote. Thanks guys for helping me out here (totally new on this ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a button

```
<button id='playbutton' className='myclass'>play</button>
```

to set the background color you need to get the element first
by using an id

```
document.getElementById('playbutton').style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

or the classname

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

there is a lot of ways to get a DOM element

note: you might want to use onClick on the button instead of using an event listener

Comment: no, no button. When a key is pressed, sound's coming. And I wanted to add visual change too, thx!

Comment: oh kk then you are pretty close just use document.getElementById() to get the element you want to change style. You can always check w3schools they have great tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: okay, I gave every key an id which I wanted to avoid (worked just with classes), now it's working, thanks a lot :)